# How to get Related List of current record in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, related-list

I have a Lightning component which I can add to any salesforce object.

As we have Related List Standard component in Lightning, how can I get that Related (Child) List of records in Lightning component?

For Eg: If I open an opportunity record, is there anyway to get Opportunity Products associated to this Opportunity in my Custom Lightning component added?

Comment: There is no way to use Standard lightning app-bulder components from  your lightning component code. Maybe to show a list you can use the new [lightning:datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.210.0.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_datatable.htm) base component

Answer (score 1):

Winter 18' has something called 'Related List Quick Links' standard component using which you can mouseover on specific related list and navigate to its record!

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lab_related_list_quick_links_comp.htm